# segmentation error in mex file

Tags: c, matlab, segmentation-fault, mex

Here is the mex code I wrote to read in a tab-delimited file. The mex file got created but it causes my MATLAB to end abruptly and give the following error. Can anyone help me where I am going wrong? Please let me know if any further information is required

Abnormal termination:
Segmentation violation

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>  

void mexFunction(int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs,const mxArray *prhs[])
{   

    FILE *ptr_file;
    const char **field_names;       /* pointers to field names */
    char *buf[1024];
    char *temp[20];
    int count;
    int i, j, k, l;
    int date_field, mva_field, qc_load_field, air_field, qc_air_field, oil_field, qc_oil_field, wind_a_field, qc_wind_a_field, wind_b_field, qc_wind_b_field, wind_c_field, qc_wind_c_field, tamb1_field, qc_tamb1_field;
    char *NAME;
    NAME=mxArrayToString(prhs[0]);
    count = 0;
//open file to count elements   
    ptr_file =fopen(NAME,"r");
    if (ptr_file != NULL)
    {
//skip first 3 lines    
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), ptr_file);
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), ptr_file);
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), ptr_file);
//start counting no. of elements    
    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), ptr_file) != NULL)
        count++;
    fclose(ptr_file);
    }
        field_names[0] = "date";
    field_names[1] = "mva";
    field_names[2] = "qc_load";
    field_names[3] = "air";
    field_names[4] = "qc_air";
    field_names[5] = "oil";
    field_names[6] = "qc_oil";
    field_names[7] = "wind_a";
    field_names[8] = "qc_wind_a";
    field_names[9] = "wind_b";
    field_names[10] = "qc_wind_b";
    field_names[11] = "wind_c";
    field_names[12] = "qc_wind_c"; 
    field_names[13] = "tamb1";
    field_names[14] = "qc_tamb1"; 

    plhs[0] = mxCreateStructMatrix(count, 1, 15, field_names);
    plhs[1] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);
    date_field = mxGetFieldNumber(plhs[0],"date");
    mva_field = mxGetFieldNumber(plhs[0],"mva");
    qc_load_field = mxGetFieldNumber(plhs[0],"qc_load");
    air_field = mxGetFieldNumber(plhs[0],"air");
    qc_air_field = mxGetFieldNumber(plhs[0],"qc_air");
    oil_field = mxGetFieldNumber(plhs[0],"oil");
    qc_oil_field = mxGetFieldNumber(plhs[0],"qc_oil");
    wind_a_field = mxGetFieldNumber(plhs[0],"wind_a");
    qc_wind_a_field = mxGetFieldNumber(plhs[0],"qc_wind_a");
    wind_b_field = mxGetFieldNumber(plhs[0],"wind_b");
    qc_wind_b_field = mxGetFieldNumber(plhs[0],"qc_wind_b");
    wind_c_field = mxGetFieldNumber(plhs[0],"wind_c");
    qc_wind_c_field = mxGetFieldNumber(plhs[0],"qc_wind_c");
    tamb1_field = mxGetFieldNumber(plhs[0],"tamb1");
    qc_tamb1_field = mxGetFieldNumber(plhs[0],"qc_tamb1");


//open file again for storing elements columnwise
    ptr_file =fopen(NAME,"r");
    if (ptr_file != NULL)
    {
//skip first 3 lines    
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), ptr_file);
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), ptr_file);
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), ptr_file);  
//start collecting data 
    for(i=0;i<count;i++){   //increment line
        //get line
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), ptr_file);
        j=0;
        k=0;
        //extract first word
        while(buf[j] != '\t'){
            temp[k] = buf[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
        temp[k] = '\0';
        j++;
        mxSetFieldByNumber(plhs[0],i,date_field,mxCreateString(temp));
//      strcpy(elem[i].date, temp);

        //extract second word
        k=0;
        while(buf[j] != '\t'){
            temp[k] = buf[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
        temp[k] = '\0';
        j++;
//      elem[i].mva = atof(temp);
        *mxGetPr(plhs[1]) = atof(temp);
        mxSetFieldByNumber(plhs[0],i,mva_field,plhs[1]);    

        //extract third word
        k=0;
        while(buf[j] != '\t'){
            temp[k] = buf[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
        temp[k] = '\0';
        j++;
//      strcpy(elem[i].qc_load, temp);  
        mxSetFieldByNumber(plhs[0],i,qc_load_field,mxCreateString(temp));
// similarly for other fields of the structure. 
    fclose(ptr_file);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are skipping the first three lines twice. Check k and j not to exceed the limits.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank you for your prompt respone. The reason I skipped the lines the first time is just to count the number of rows that I had to read in and then the next time it is done just to actually read in the data. I had run the C code and it gave me the desired outputs. Then I struggled with mexing since I have never done it before and after removing all the errors I had in formatting, this is what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a segfault because rather than `field_names` pointing to somewhere you can treat as an array of `const char *`, it points nowhere because it's uninitialised. Hence

```
const char **field_names;    /* pointer to nowhere */
...
field_names[0] = "date";     /* dereferences invalid pointer and BANG */
```

What you want is actually:

```
const char *field_names[15]; /* array of pointers to const char */
...
field_names[0] = "date";     /* all is well and good */
...
```

**Key C fact:** pointers are not arrays and arrays are not pointers, but in *some* circumstances an array will be implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element - such that it is still correct to pass this `field_names` array to `mxCreateStructMatrix()` in place of a `const char **`.

---

However, fix that and you'll then hit the problems with this:

```
plhs[1] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);
```

Firstly, since you haven't checked that `nlhs` is at least 2, `plhs[1]` may well not exist and similarly blow up when you try to set its value. IIRC, setting `plhs[0]` without checking is *probably* OK, since even if `nlhs == 0`, `plhs[0]` *should* point to `Ans` instead of an explicit output variable, but really it's good practice to check `nlhs` before doing anything and act accordingly. Similarly using `prhs[0]` without checking `nrhs > 0` isn't advisable.

Secondly, later on you'll end up assigning this same `mxArray` to multiple fields of multiple structures which is not a valid thing to do (and may cause Matlab to crash later due to heap corruption). Even if it were allowed I don't think you want every numeric field in the whole structure array pointing to one single `double` that's been overwritten n-thousand times...

Third, I don't quite understand the use of `plhs[1]` at all, unless you really *do* want a mandatory second output of "whatever the last number read was". What I suspect you were going for is this:

```
mxArray *mxtmp;
...
    /* in parsing loop */
    mxtmp = mxCreateDoubleScalar(atof(temp));
    mxSetFieldByNumber(plhs[0], i, mva_field, mxtmp);
```

---

Elsewhere, whilst indeed you *can* store `char` values in pointers, it's not a sane or meaningful thing to do and in this case is clearly another mistake:

```
char *buf[1024];  /* array of pointers to char - wrong */
char *temp[20];

char buf[1024];   /* array of char - right */
char temp[20];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it. Initially I had not used plhs[1] at all. However, mxtmp that you talk about, when I used that, I was constantly getting an error saying that this was illegal use of mxArray. Is it that I will have to declare as many mxArrays as many times I use mxCreateDoubleScalar?

Comment: @user2971034 You can't declare an `mxArray` directly as it's an incomplete type - `mxtmp` is a pointer, which is allowed. It's not even strictly necessary, there's nothing _technically_ wrong with `mxSetFieldByNumber(plhs[0], i, mva_field, mxCreateDoubleScalar(atof(temp)));` other than long lines and nested function calls being hard to read, and having no way to check the return value of `mxCreateDoubleScalar()` before using it.

Comment: There is this last problem I am facing.The date I get is in chars and so are some other fields. What I want to do is to form these fields into vectors. It is fine for the integer fields but for the fields that contain characters, if I read them all in an array, I get all the characters in a string like'5/1/2000 0:00 5/1/2000 0:01...'. I am trying to use mxCreateCharMatrixFromStrings but it is not working. There is error of too few arguments to call and missing ')'

mxArray *strtmp
strtmp=mxCreateCharMatrixFromStrings((mwSize)count, (const char **) (plhs[0].date));

Comment: I know that the problem is in plhs[0], it cannot be accessed like this I feel. But how can I copy it to a different array of strings?

Comment: mxGetFieldByNumber will get me only one element of that field at a time. Should I then use a for loop to get all elements into an array of strings and then use this function of mxCreateCharMatrixFromStrings?